# Are Russian words пять (five), пясть (fist), пятка (heel) related? What about English "fist"?

Tags: english, etymology, proto-indo-european, russian, numerals

I wonder whether the PIE word for five in fact meant "fist", in other words, when people counted, they closed their fingers and when they obtained the closed fist, it was "five"?

Similarly to how the word for right hand gave the PIE word for ten, ***decm*** (from dec- "right-hand-side", ***decsnea̯*** "right hand"). In other words, people started to count from their left hand and when they completed the right hand as well, they would have ten.

Comment: Five being derived from fist or finger, while far from settled, is a lot less contentious than ten being derived from hand, much less the right hand specifically.

Comment: See [the chart](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/penkwe.pdf), which lists only English cognates and descendants. There are lots more, like _Punjab_.

Comment: As wiktionary already mentions "full", consider further *pan-* "all", from Gk. *pas*, from \*peh2-? Maybe assume a sense *package*, and cp. words for *glove*. I know I went wild once trying to derive *shoe* (or even *hand*!) from *Handschuh* "glove". Now cp. Ne-Pali [panja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%BE#Nepali) "glove; claw, paw; (card games) five" versus *pyjama* from Persian "leg garments".